# VOIP in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

As we know, MS announced that there will be native support of VOIP in WP8 and as per statement there is one new API added under this namespace "Microsoft.Phone.Networking.Voip" and it has some Methods too. Is someone worked on VOIP in WP8 and used the native libraries to make SIP calls. Or we need to use some third party native libraries to make SIP calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VoIP API doesn't come with any specific communication APIs, it's merely a API for integrating into the phone service for getting incoming calls while the application is not running, and running calls while the application is in the background.

You'll have to integrate all other features, such as PUSH, Audio Routing, etc. yourself on top of the API that the WP8 SDK provides.

So to initiate SIP calls, you'll need your own native library, and integrate the WP8 VoIP API on top of that.

Comment: Jogenson: As I am getting from your own words We need to use our own library like PJSIP, doubango for SIP Calls initiating and to do rest things. Is There Any SIP Library Comes for wp7 yet ??

Comment: We're not shipping any out of Redmond to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen It's been an year since this answer. Any relevant library for VoIP on WP8 ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not unless someone wrote one, which I doubt anyone did.